# How to enter the url scheme to open the app?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, url-scheme

When I use an h5 page to write the following code:
`window.location.href="mqqapi://card/show_pslcard?src_type=internal&version=1&card_type=group&uin=xxx";`,
it can open app。

If I type "mqqapi://card/show_pslcard? src_type=internal&version=1&card_type=group&uin=xxx", the browser uses the search engine to search for this content.

why?  image is my chrome app version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJvMu.jpg)

input this url scheme，open app

Comment: but you have typed intentionally this "address" in omnibar, so you want to open address or search for this query, thats how this field works in every browser. opening apps with uri/scheme works only by clicking url, not manually writting it anywhere hoping that app will figure out what to do with entered text

Comment: To open the app, enter the url scheme in chrome on windows. So I thought Android would work.

Comment: browser may try to open uri as address, if fail may check if this url can be handled by another app, if not then at least may search the query. but browsers, as all other apps, are trying their best for keeping user inside, as longer app usage = more engagement = more often visits = more earning.. in this case search results are showing some ads, if browser would open your app it loses own user (and earning)... and your case is pretty rare, users in very most cases are entering address or trying to search with this field. no one will be re-writting such complicated uri as you posted...